# Imagemagick mogrify jacks up linux server load average

Tags: linux, imagemagick

AFAIK, the theory says multiply factor of 1 per CPU core to find out your optimal load average. So, server with 8 CPU cores optimal load average would be 8, 16 cores = 16 and so on. However, when using Imagemagick's mogrify I can see huge load average numbers:

```
top - 14:00:44 up 9 days, 20:12,  6 users,  load average: 130.37, 87.53, 56.94
Tasks: 588 total,  11 running, 577 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 99.8%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  49555072k total, 33129928k used, 16425144k free,  3813092k buffers
Swap: 23438824k total,    47276k used, 23391548k free, 26145156k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                    
29490 user1      20   0  121m  33m 2728 R  240  0.1   9:10.52 mogrify                                                                    
29337 user1      20   0  121m  33m 2728 R  234  0.1  12:01.94 mogrify                                                                    
29882 user1      20   0  121m  33m 2728 R  231  0.1   3:57.54 mogrify                                                                    
29232 user1      20   0  121m  33m 2728 R  223  0.1  11:34.54 mogrify                                                                    
29514 user1      20   0  122m  33m 2728 R  223  0.1   9:22.84 mogrify                                                                    
29689 user1      20   0  121m  33m 2728 R  219  0.1   7:28.18 mogrify                                                                    
29204 user1      20   0  121m  33m 2728 R  206  0.1  12:21.33 mogrify
```

As it is clear from `top` - no issues with the server. This behavior occurs only when call `mogrify`.

Why does it happen?
How I can fix it or at least tune down a bit?

Thanks!

Edit: Usually they run that long. The server is responsive as usual. I am processing 618 images on average size 2.5 MB. The load is spread between few servers, which `top` outputs look very identical. I have read [this thread](http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15876&sid=c665b73e2c8a1ec5277d3452be39b3f6&start=15) which I am yet to test. Seems to me that mogrify (or Imagemagick) "overestimate" the CPUs. Hence the 200+% CPU usage per job.

Comment: These processes seem to be running for a very long time.  Is this normal?

Comment: hm, didn't even notice that.  12 minutes *is* pretty long for automated image manipulation - are they really big images?

Comment: Is ImageMagick multithreaded? `top -H` may help.

Comment: Yes, it is multithreaded. I think the default is 8 threads per CPU core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the solution is. I ran tests against 2 versions of `ImageMagick` - 6.5.1 and 6.5.7. The old version comes with Ubuntu Karmic 9.10, the newer one with Ubuntu Lucid 10.04. Both 64-bit versions. I noticed the 6.5.7 version is faster than 6.5.1 and also does not load the server that much. It produced normal single digit load as one could expect. For both versions `mogrify` was multithreaded.

So, now I am satisfied. If I find some spare time will check what the exact difference is.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing graphics processing.  This is inherently CPU intensive.

The solution is to stop doing graphics processing, or at least do less of it - update whatever is calling `mogrify` so it can't run as many parallel tasks.  If that isn't an option split the load (add another server and send some of the work there).

---

Note that if your load average is 130 and your system is still responsive and doing everything you need it to do in a timely fashion you don't have a problem, you have a "problem" (It doesn't look good, at a glance any sysadmin will tell you it's probably something bad and you should look at solutions like what I described above, but if it's not hurting anything and it doesn't get substantially worse as you scale up you may be able to ignore it as "normal for this environment").